# How to change the crystal reports page size in vs 2005?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How to change the crystal reports page size in vs 2005 ?

Answer (score 1):

The page size of the report is derived from the printer settings of the report. You can change this in the printer setup. So for instance if you want a larger surface perhaps you can go for a larger paper size like A4 or A3 depending on your needs